# Uncaught TypeError: c2 is not a function

Tags: reactjs, zoom-sdk

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ZoomMtg } from "@zoomus/websdk";
import "./Meet.css";
import SpeechText from "./SpeechText";

ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib("https://source.zoom.us/2.14.0/lib", "/av");
ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareWebSDK();
ZoomMtg.i18n.load("en-US");
ZoomMtg.i18n.reload("en-US");

const KJUR = require("jsrsasign");

const Meet = () => {
 var sdkKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SDK_KEY;

 var meetURL = "";
 var meetNo = "";
 var pass = "";
 var role = 0; // 0 means user and 1 means host
 var userName = "NIK";
 var userEmail = "";
 var registrantToken = "";
 var zakToken = "";
 var leaveURL = "https://zoom.us/"; // when the meeting is over it will redirect to this url

 const [ele, setEle] = useState(
 document.getElementsByClassName("footer__btns-container")
 );
 const getSign = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 // tesing the url against the regex which is the valid form of the url
 if (
  !meetURL ||
  !meetURL.match(/^https:\/\/us05web\.zoom\us\/j\/\d+\?pwd=[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)
 ) {
  alert("Please Enter a valid meet link");
  return;
 }

pass = meetURL.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
meetNo = meetURL.split("?")[0].split("/")[4];
const iat = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 30;
const exp = iat + 60 * 60 * 2;
const oHeader = { alg: "HS256", typ: "JWT" };
const oPayload = {
sdkKey: process.env.REACT_SDK_KEY,
mn: meetNo,
role: role,
iat: iat,
exp: exp,
appKey: process.env.REACT_SDK_KEY,
tokenExp: iat + 60 * 60 * 2,
};
const sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader);
const sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload);
const signature = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(
"HS256",
sHeader,
sPayload,
process.env.REACT_SDK_KEY
);
startMeet(signature);
};

const startMeet = (signature) => {
document.getElementById("zmmtg-root").style.display = "block";


ZoomMtg.init({
  leaveUrl: leaveURL,
  success: (success) => {
    ZoomMtg.join({
      signature: signature,
      sdkKey: sdkKey,
      meetingNumber: meetNo,
      passWord: pass,
      userName: userName,
      userEmail: userEmail,
      tk: registrantToken,
      zak: zakToken,
      success: (success) => {
        
        var refreshInterval = setInterval(() => {
          if (document.getElementsByClassName("footer__btns-container")) {
            setEle(
              document.getElementsByClassName("footer__btns-container")
            );
          }
        }, 2000);
        if (ele.length !== 0) {
          const createdEle = document.createElement("div");
          createdEle.setAttribute("id", "custom-foot-bar");
          ele[0].appendChild(createdEle);
          ReactDOM.render(
            <SpeechText />,
            document.getElementById("custom-foot-bar")
          );
          clearInterval(refreshInterval);
        }
        console.log(success);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  },
  error: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  },
});
};

return (
<>
  <main>
    <h1>GPT Zoom Bot</h1>
    <div className="meetCredentials">
      <label>Meeting URL</label>
      <input
        autoFocus
        type="text"
        id="meetingUrl"
        placeholder="Enter the meeting link"
        required
        defaultValue={meetURL}
        onChange={(e) => {
          meetURL = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={getSign}>Join Meeting</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</>
);
};
```

export default Meet;

Above code enables users to join a Zoom meeting by providing a meeting URL and initializes and joins the Zoom meeting using the Zoom Meeting SDK, and dynamically renders a custom footer bar with a SpeechText component once the bot is admitted to the meeting.

The following error shows in the console
[image]

Help would be much appreciated.

If the above code runs then it will show a input box to enter the meeting link.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, welcome to Stack Overflow. As a convention, error messages should be included using Stack Overflow's built-in code formatting option. It makes for easier copy-pasting and viewing.

Comment: Just a note. I think the problem is not with your code, but more likely with the function `ZoomMtg` you import from "@zoomus/websdk".

Comment: @Galbert any solution for the problem or any alternative?

Comment: 'c2 ZoomMtg zoomus/websdk problem' on google and click on first result. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BgkLvH7T0Y